# asp.net table like calendar control

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, calendar

I'm looking for a calendar control, which can show current month and 2 months a head.
The output format, should be like a table/excel document.

Here's an example (only showing the top of the calendar):
[image: Picture showing the top of the calendar]

I need to be able to add events, to a specific date on the calendar.

Comment: You could use something like Full Calendar and just display a calender for each month http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: @KevinKunderman Thanks, great plugin and easy to work with. Make an answer below, and I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [Full Calander](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) and just display a calender for each month arshaw.com/fullcalendar

Answer (score 0):

You won't find exact same structure or code, you will need to manipulate some existing plugins or code, or create a one from scratch.

Try this
http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/custommenu.html